# Error in Updating Maven - Spring MVC project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC framework.I am trying to develop a web application following [these steps here](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-beginner-tutorial-with-spring-tool-suite-ide). I was going on well until I reached the stage of updating Maven to include dependencies; I got the following error after *right click project --> Maven --> Update Project -tick Force Update of Snapshots/Releases --> Finish.*

**UPDATE**

The following errors is shown in the IDE:

```
`ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact javax.inject:javax.inject:pom:1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org pom.xml /HelloSpringMVC line 1  Maven Dependency Problem`
```

`CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.5.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org   pom.xml /HelloSpringMVC line 136    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem`

Comment: Provide more details about this error.

Comment: Show us your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Set up the same example at my end and generated the issue.

Perform the following steps to fix the issue

right click project --> Maven --> Update Project -tick Force Update of Snapshots/Releases --> Finish.